# Trying to have HTML image auto resize when browser size shrinks

Tags: html

I'm rather bad at HTML and looking to have an image resize itself automatically when the browser size is changed (zooming in and out). This is for an ebay listing template. The template as a whole is perfect minus the image does not fit the same when zooming in and out. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
<h1 style="text-align: center; line-height: 100%"><font face="Arial" style="font-size: 14pt; color: rgb(53, 53, 53);"><img alt="Aleq" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid" src="https://example.com">
```

Answer (score 2):

For the image to resize based on the browser width change, you can take a look at this resource. It talks about few css tricks you can do to make your images responsive.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

Comment: I don't believe ebay supports CSS of any kind. Is there HTML coding to do the same without CSS? It looks like the only way is to actually have multiple pictures at different sizes in the code?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of doing this would be to add a max-width property to your image in your css file.

For example, if you gave your image a class of "stackoverflow-img" it would be:

```
<style>
    .stackoverflow-image{
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I will give this a go. I was under the impression that ebay doesn't support CSS in it's templates.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much about ebay listings, however according to [these ebay best practices](https://pages.ebay.com/sell/itemdescription/bestpractices.html#ResponsiveDesignBestPractice) it looks possible.

Also, you are using style tags in your current code, so you could just add the max-width property to the image tag there.